# Extracting negative numbers in a string

Tags: python

How can I acess the negative numbers in strings like this ('((-1,-5,-1),(3,1,-3),(4,-1))')
 I already tried  slicing and got  '-' and '5' instead of -5

Comment: have you tried 're' (regex) module?

Comment: Haven't heard of it,but I can't use anything that is not on the original python documentation

Comment: Oh,just checked that it is a builtin,will use it then

Comment: Is your string a tuple? You could switch it to a tuple and then put the numbers in a list and from that list take only the negative values.

Comment: Yes,I want to acess all the values,but with slicing I had a problem with the negative ones.Will try that.

Comment: Please add the code that you tried. It may be a simple mistake or misunderstanding of how slicing works.

Comment: @JackMoody is there a way that I can just remove the ' ' and get a tuple

Comment: @usr2564301 I just did something like [t[1],t[2]],and I got [-,1] instead of [-1,x]

Comment: Add your exact code to the question. What was `t`, for example? You can always use [edit] to clarify what you are asking. As a new member of Stack Overflow you may want to read the introductory [tour] some time and browse the [Help].

Answer (score 2):

If the string is a valid Python tuple, you could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

ts = '((-1,-5,-1),(3,1,-3),(4,-1))'
ts = ast.literal_eval(ts)

numbers = [e for t in ts for e in t]
print(numbers)
```

**Output**

```
[-1, -5, -1, 3, 1, -3, 4, -1]
```

Or, you could use regular expressions through the built-in [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
import re

numbers = re.compile('-?\d+')
ts = '((-1,-5,-1),(3,1,-3),(4,-1))'
result = list(map(int, numbers.findall(ts)))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[-1, -5, -1, 3, 1, -3, 4, -1]
```

The pattern `-?\d+` means match a group of digits (`\d+`) that can possibly be preceded by a minus sign (`-?`).